# Seeing hangs (no timeout) on aiobotocore response['Body'].read(...)

Tags: boto3, python-asyncio, botocore

Using aiobotocore I'm creating the client using:

```
import botocore
import aiobotocore

s3_session = aiobotocore.get_session(loop=loop)
client = s3_session.create_client(
    's3',
    config=botocore.client.Config(connect_timeout=10, read_timeout=10, retries={'max_attempts': 0}),
    endpoint_url=endpoint_url,
)
```

Later on I've got an async function that's reading in 8k chunks:

```
async def aio_read(bucket, key, range_header):
    s3_object = await self.client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Range=range_header)
    s3_iostream = s3_object['Body']

    b = None
    body_data = b''
    while b != b'':
        b = await s3_iostream.read(8192)
        body_data += b
        print('{}> len(b) / len(body_data) = {}/{}'.format(uuid, len(b), len(body_data)))
```

The downloads I'm testing with are 1MB in size, read in 8k chunks. When I run 100 processes in parallel I usually get a few hanging, and with the `print` statement above I can see that one of the `aio_read` functions is stopping mid-way through reading the file.

The body read operation seems to time out and then hangs indefinitely.

Is there a way to get an exception out of aiobotocore if a read timeout occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that the timeout is per coroutine, you should not iterate on read multiple times within a single coroutine, rather you should submit multiple coroutines to the event thread to run `read` mutliple times. You can't read the entire file at once in the case of large files either. The approach that works well for me is to submit separate coroutines to the even loop each to read a 1MB chunk from the Body iostream. This way you don't end up with large files that time out within 1 coroutine, nor do you end up with a large number of coroutines which end being overhead and consuming too much time on the event loop (which is 1 thread, 1 core max), 8k was too small.